# ES Connection Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using this code in lambda to connect to ES Domain:

```
host = os.environ['esDomain']
print("ES DOMAIN IS..........")
region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']

service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()


def connectES():
    print('Connecting to the ES Endpoint {0}')
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                       credentials.secret_key,
                       region, service,
                       session_token=credentials.token)
    try:
        es = Elasticsearch(
            hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
            http_auth=awsauth,
            use_ssl=True,
            timeout=30,
            verify_certs=True,
            connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
        return es
    except Exception as E:
        print("Unable to connect to {0}")
        print(E)
        exit(3)


print("sucess seting up es")
```

I am getting this error in cloud watch; I have tried putting timeout= 30 sec, also used retry, but error remained same:

```
ConnectionTimeout caused by - ConnectTimeout(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vpc-caci-search-engine-7q4ctnjex5ltbq4beipo7hxndm.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /document/_doc (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2ad5341828>, 'Connection to vpc-caci-search-engine-7q4ctnjex5ltbq4beipo7hxndm.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=30)')))
```

Comment: Can you provide more details. Is your ES public, is your lambda in VPC? What are your ES policies?

Comment: it allows Amazon Elasticsearch Service to access other AWS services such as EC2 Networking APIs. Yes, lambda is in VPC, and ES s public

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, lambda is in VPC, and ES s public

Thus, the connection timeout happens because a lambda function in a VPC does not have access to the internet by default. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, the function **can't access the internet** unless your VPC provides access.

You either have to deploy your ES domain in the same VPC, or enable your lambda function to connect to the internet as described in:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

If the lambda does not have to be in the VPC, you can just remove it from it.

Comment: I tried this but still it gives connection timeout error

Comment: @aa16034 Then you have to update your question will all your lambda and VPC setup, subnets, security groups, network ACLs, lambda permissions, etc. Something is blocking these connections, and without those details its difficult to further  what.